# Loading from a nib UIView unused Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

since migrating to Swift 3 for the following code:

```
func setup() {

        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("SomeNib", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as! UIView
        self.addSubview(customView)
        customView.frame = self.bounds


    }
```

I am now getting the warning: `Expression of type 'UIView' is unused`. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 7):

You never declared and set the customView which is why the compiler is complaining about not using the result of `loadNibNamed`.

`let customView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("SomeNib", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as! UIView`

Comment: oh I wonder why it works then...Actually I have an outlet from `customView` in the same file as `setup()`. If I have the outlet can I just remove the `loadNibNamed` completely?